# Create folder in custom photo album

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

I have a custom album in which my app saves picture from camera. I am wondering if there is a way I can create folders inside my album so I can stack certain images inside it?

**ANSWER**

As fellow members mentioned, sadly there is no way you can create a folder inside album.

Comment: You cannot create a folder, but you can make a new Album.

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding this right: album inside album?

Comment: You should accept Michael Craun's answer.. I've been an iOS dev on OS for 10 years and this was the most helpful answer I've ever seen on here

Answer (score 7):

You should try code below. It's **Swift 3.0** syntaxe. :)

```
import Foundation
import Photos


class CustomPhotoAlbum: NSObject {
    static let albumName = "Album Name"
    static let sharedInstance = CustomPhotoAlbum()

    var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!

    override init() {
        super.init()

        if let assetCollection = fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() {
            self.assetCollection = assetCollection
            return
        }

        if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status: PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in
                ()
            })
        }

        if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
            self.createAlbum()
        } else {
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(requestAuthorizationHandler)
        }
    }

    func requestAuthorizationHandler(status: PHAuthorizationStatus) {
        if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
            // ideally this ensures the creation of the photo album even if authorization wasn't prompted till after init was done
            print("trying again to create the album")
            self.createAlbum()
        } else {
            print("should really prompt the user to let them know it's failed")
        }
    }

    func createAlbum() {
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: CustomPhotoAlbum.albumName)   // create an asset collection with the album name
        }) { success, error in
            if success {
                self.assetCollection = self.fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum()
            } else {
                print("error \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

    func fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() -> PHAssetCollection? {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", CustomPhotoAlbum.albumName)
        let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)

        if let _: AnyObject = collection.firstObject {
            return collection.firstObject
        }
        return nil
    }

    func save(image: UIImage) {
        if assetCollection == nil {
            return                          // if there was an error upstream, skip the save
        }

        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
            let assetPlaceHolder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
            let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection)
            let enumeration: NSArray = [assetPlaceHolder!]
            albumChangeRequest!.addAssets(enumeration)

        }, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly does this create a new folder inside my album? :) This is just code for creating custom album.

Comment: Ok sorry, I tought you wanted just to create custom photo album.

Like @byJeevan told you, you cannot create a folder in custom photo album obviously. :)

Comment: This is what I needed yes, thank you for confirmation. :)

Comment: ISSOU ! LA CHANCLA ! EL BAÑADOR !

Answer (score 7):

You can add albums within folders in the user's Photos Albums. I just figured out how to do it, today:

```
import Photos

class PhotoManager {
    static let instance = PhotoManager()
    var folder: PHCollectionList?

    /// Fetches an existing folder with the specified identifier or creates one with the specified name
    func fetchFolderWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String, name: String) {
        let fetchResult = PHCollectionList.fetchCollectionLists(withLocalIdentifiers: [identifier], options: nil)
        guard let folder = fetchResult.firstObject else {
            createFolderWithName(name)
            return
        }

        self.folder = folder
    }

    /// Creates a folder with the specified name
    private func createFolderWithName(_ name: String) {
        var placeholder: PHObjectPlaceholder?

        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let changeRequest = PHCollectionListChangeRequest.creationRequestForCollectionList(withTitle: name)
            placeholder = changeRequest.placeholderForCreatedCollectionList
        }) { (success, error) in
            guard let placeholder = placeholder else { return }
            let fetchResult = PHCollectionList.fetchCollectionLists(withLocalIdentifiers: [placeholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)
            guard let folder = fetchResult.firstObject else { return }

            self.folder = folder
        }
    }

    /// Creates an album with the specified name
    private func createAlbumWithName(_ name: String, completion: @escaping (PHAssetCollection?) -> Void) {
        guard let folder = folder else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        var placeholder: PHObjectPlaceholder?
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let listRequest = PHCollectionListChangeRequest(for: folder)
            let createAlbumRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: name)
            listRequest?.addChildCollections([createAlbumRequest.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection] as NSArray)
            placeholder = createAlbumRequest.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection
        }) { (success, error) in
            guard let placeholder = placeholder else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            let fetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(withLocalIdentifiers: [placeholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)
            let album = fetchResult.firstObject
            completion(album)
        }
    }

    /// Saves the image to a new album with the specified name
    func saveImageToAlbumInRootFolder(_ albumName: String, image: UIImage?, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        createAlbumWithName(albumName) { (album) in
            guard let album = album else {
                return
            }

            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: album)
                let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image!)
                let photoPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset!
                albumChangeRequest?.addAssets([photoPlaceholder] as NSArray)
            }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
                if success {
                    completion(nil)
                } else if let error = error {
                    // Failed with error
                } else {
                    // Failed with no error
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to do something like this:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let identifier = defaults.string(forKey: "myFolder")!
PhotoManager.instance.fetchFolderWithIdentifier(identifier, name: "My Folder")
PhotoManager.instance.saveImageToAlbumInRootFolder("My Album", image: UIImage(named: "my_image")) { (error) in
     // Handle error
}
```

Comment: PhotoManager.instance.fetchFolderWithIdentifier(identifier, name: "My Folder")
 in this method multiple name created.

Comment: That's strange, I experienced this while figuring it out, but I've not seen it since coming up with this solution. In fact, I just checked the source code, again, and saved 15 out of 15 photos to Photos > root > My Folder > My Album... Are you sure it's not being called multiple times?

Comment: @MichaelCraun You really saved lot of time of mine. Big Thanks.

Comment: Yeah man, this is post from someone with like 50k rep, not 50!  Would like to see more from you brotha!