# appendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use appendingPathComponent on URL instead.a

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Swift 4, Xcode 9, and development target iOS 11.0.

I am trying to append a custom folder (MyFolder) to the `path` variable.

```
let outputFilePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appending("MyFolder").appendingPathComponent((outputFileName as NSString).appendingPathExtension("mov")!)
```

But builder is giving error message:

> appendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use appendingPathComponent on URL instead.

I know, I am doing some silly mistake. Can you kindly help me in this?

Comment: Why are you attempting to use `NSString` in your Swift code?

Comment: `let outputFileURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(outputFileName).appendingPathExtension("mov")` and if you need the path `let outputFilePath = outputFileURL.path`

Comment: Why do you need a subfolder to save a temporary file?

Comment: Actually I am trying to save a photo in a custom folder in side My Albums

Comment: What is My Albums? is it a folder located in your Documents directory? Or is it located in your Bundle? The code you posted above you are trying to save it inside a temporary directory and we don't even know if that subfolder exists.

Comment: I realized my mistake. I am trying to append a subfolder in temporary directory. I am trying to save a photo in a custom folder in  PHPhotoLibrary. PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
       let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
       options.shouldMoveFile = true
       let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
       creationRequest.addResource(with: .video, fileURL: outputFileURL, options: options)
      }                                                                                           Dont know how to add the custom folder "MyFolder" in that.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phcollectionlistchangerequest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43118032/2303865

Comment: Thank you Leo Dabus for the links. I am working on my code and let you know the result. Thank you once again.

Comment: Hi photo/video not saving in the new folder. Can you kindly help me with this?  following is the query.  let albumName = “TestAlbum”
let assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: albumName )
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
if let _: AnyObject = collection.firstObject {
collection.firstObject
}

Comment: let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
options.shouldMoveFile = true
let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
creationRequest.addResource(with: .video, fileURL: outputFileURL, options: options)

Answer (score 1):

Use this line

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("MyFolder").appendingPathComponent(outputFileName).appendingPathExtension("mov")
```

instead of

```
(NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appending("MyFolder").appendingPathComponent((outputFileName as NSString).appendingPathExtension("mov")!)
```

This will return you a `url`  and use `url.Path` to get its path in `string` .
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**Check below code for reference in document Directory**

```
class func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("FolderName")

        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error creating directory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return dataPath
    }
```

**For Appending Files in Folder You can use this**

```
//name for file to be added 
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
// storing a Audio File in Directory 
let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(uuid).m4a")
```

**To get Names of Files Available in the respected Folder created**

```
    //This function returns a Array with file names Available
    class func getListOfRecordingsAvailable() -> [String] {
            var fileNameArray = [String]()
            let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
            let myFilesPath = documentDirectoryPath.appending("/FolderName")
            let files = FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: myFilesPath)

            while let file = files?.nextObject() {
                //myfilesPath - Path
                //file - fileName
                fileNameArray.append(file as! String)
            }

            print(fileNameArray)
            return fileNameArray


}
```

Comment: According to the error message and the API evolution Apple highly recommends to use the URL related API of `FileManager` for example `createDirectory(at:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:)` and `contentsOfDirectory(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:)`. `enumerator(atPath` is outdated.