# How to create a folder inside Gallery programmatically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, photo-gallery, save-image

I recently noticed the following options in my iOS Gallery. (refer pic)

1. New Album
2. New Folder
3. New Shared Album

[image]

I have a requirement of creating an Camera app which stores the pictures inside the Gallery in a hierarchy. e.g. AppName/Some_grp/Some_grp2/picture1_timestamp.jpeg

Where **AppName & Some_grp are folder** (Not Albums) and **Some_grp2 is an Album.**

I am able to create an Album in the Gallery programatically, but not a Folder.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117959/create-folder-in-custom-photo-album

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
 func createFolder(_ name: String) {
    var placeholder: PHObjectPlaceholder?

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let changeRequest = PHCollectionListChangeRequest.creationRequestForCollectionList(withTitle: name)
        placeholder = changeRequest.placeholderForCreatedCollectionList
    }) { (success, error) in
        guard let placeholder = placeholder else { return }
        let fetchResult = PHCollectionList.fetchCollectionLists(withLocalIdentifiers: [placeholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)
        guard let folder = fetchResult.firstObject else { return }
    }
}
```