# How To create a folder inside a Album in iOS iPhone Using Xamarin form

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Hello Developer I want to create a a directory inside a Album in iOS using Xamarin form ,I need to use this directory to store all my capture images

Comment: I'm using xamarin form ,Please provide links for this language related

Comment: I have try this and its work but I want create a folder inside a albums with my project name and store all images inside this created  folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create folder in custom photo album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117959/create-folder-in-custom-photo-album)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PhotoLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums?language=objc) to manage picture in album.

We can use it through **dependencyService** in Xamarin.Forms.

Here is a document about it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

I also create a simple test about creating album in ios:

**IOS implement code:**

```
[assembly:Dependency(typeof(CreateAlbumService))]
namespace My_Forms_Test3.iOS
{
    public class CreateAlbumService : ICreateAlbumService
    { 
        public void CreateAlbum()
        {
          PHPhotoLibrary.SharedPhotoLibrary.PerformChanges(() => { PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.CreateAssetCollection("TestAlbum"); },(issuccess,error)=> { if (!issuccess) Console.WriteLine(error); });
        }
      
    }
}
```

**result:**

[image]

Comment: @Adraina zhua yes I have try this and its work but I want create a folder inside a albums with my project name and store all images inside this created  folder

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117959/create-folder-in-custom-photo-album